# Why does processing <Page in Xaml file blow up in Uno project for Android?

Tags: android, uno-platform

I have an app built on the Uno platform that builds and runs fine on UWP.  When I try to build for Android, every Xaml file blows up trying to process <Page.  Wow, the first bytes in the files!  So I assume that something very basic is overlooked.

Searching for previous similar questions only refer to IntelliSense errors, statements that the app has indeed been built, keeping the target set to UWP when compiling for Android, and even a fellow who suggested altering the Build Action for App.xaml.  None of this fixes this problem and the build really does fail.

All software is up-to-date as of 6/20/2021.  My build machine is running latest Windows 10.

Any help is appreciated.  What am I missing?

Comment: Would it be easy for you to give repro steps from a project creation using the template? ... or a link to a repro somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, vacation.  I'll retry my effort and get back with more information if problem persists